# Can you get data from a mass update of a MySQL database showing only the data that has been changed in the DB with PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, ajax

I have a PHP/MySQL/JavaScript application for SugarCRM that I am building which will be a Project Management app.

Tasks can be organized into `Task Lists` and also there sort order sorted with drag and drop which then saves the order number into a `sort_order` database column on the Task DB table.

It gets a little more complex by making sure to only update the `date_modified` database column when that particular task record has other fields changed and not just the sort order column on the record.

For example if you drag and re-arrange the sort order of 20 records starting at record 15.  Then only records 1-15 will have the `sort_order` DB column changed.
  On these 15 updated records you might only be updating the status or title of 2 of those records.  In that case it should only update the date_modified column on those 2 records and not the 15 records!

---

**The SQL below creates a new DB record if one does not exist with matching ID.  IF one exist, then it will update only the fields that have changed and are different from the prior saved data value**

```
private function _addOrUpdateTaskRecord(
    $taskId,
    $projectId,
    $created_by_user_id,
    $modified_user_id,
    $name,
    $description,
    $status,
    $priority,
    $type,
    $date_entered,
    $date_modified,
    $date_started,
    $date_completed,
    $date_due,
    $milestone_id,
    $assigned_user_id,
    $sort_order,
    $heading){

    $sql = "
        INSERT INTO
            $this->tasksDbTableName(task_id, project_id, created_by_user_id, modified_user_id, name, description, status, priority, type, date_entered, date_modified, date_started, date_completed, date_due, milestone_id, assigned_user_id, sort_order, heading)
        VALUES
            ($db->quote($taskId), '$projectId', '$created_by_user_id', '$modified_user_id', '$name', '$description', '$status', '$priority', '$type', UTC_TIMESTAMP(), UTC_TIMESTAMP(), '$date_started', '$date_completed', '$date_due', '$milestone_id', '$assigned_user_id', '$sort_order', '$heading')
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
            date_modified = (CASE
                WHEN name <> values(name)
                OR description <> values(description)
                OR status <> values(status)
                OR type <> values(type)
                OR priority <> values(priority)
                  THEN UTC_TIMESTAMP()
                  ELSE date_modified
            END),
            modified_user_id='$modified_user_id',
            name='$name',
            description='$description',
            status='$status',
            priority='$priority',
            type='$type',
            date_started='$date_started',
            date_completed='$date_completed',
            date_due='$date_due',
            milestone_id='$milestone_id',
            assigned_user_id='$assigned_user_id',
            sort_order='$sort_order',
            heading='$heading'";

    $insertOrUpdateTasks = $this->db->query($sql);

    return $insertOrUpdateTasks;

}
```

---

**Problem**

For the most part this works great.  With tehtheception that I allow the user to update the task records on a mass edit screen using AJAX.

The problem is that a `date_started` and `date_completed` DB column are initially stored in the page DOM as a hidden form filed in this format is they are not yet set in the DB `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

After the first AJAX save on a modified record, these date values are updated in the DB.  IN the DOM though they still will have this  `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

So you then make update number 2 on some other records without reloading page from last AJAX save and then your new dates get over-written in the DB with  `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.

I need to somehow update the DOM hidden form field with the new dateTIme values that are created in the DB.

The problem is since my query does not really show me which records got updated, I cant get the value that is saved in each one for the dates to be able to update the DOM =(

---

**Idea #1**

When a field in the task row form in the DOM is changed, update those date values right away in the DOM.

The issue is if you wait 20 minutes to hit the save button, then that date is way off from the DB value.

Also if you make changes and then leave page and do not even make the save, then you just messed up that record big time!

---

**Idea #2**

My perfect solution would be able to somehow return the values I want returned on a record (columns I define) for each record that is actually updated as a JSON response and then with JavaScript iterate any updated records and update the hidden form datetime fields!

With my query above, I do not think that is possible though and my app might need a complete re-structure for this part.

**Any ideas?**

---

**Idea #3**
If I could even get an array of all records that had a value updated, I could even make another query to get the DateTime values on all them and update the DOM for each matching task record in DOM.

---

**Idea #4**

Simply have my AJAX save every little change made like every `n of seconds` and not even have a save button or just have it keep auto-saving so only 1 records is saved at a time instead of like 100 at once.  This method would allow to update the DOM datetime value and have it be within seconds of the DB save but requires a big re-write on the app

---

**UDPATE**

A new idea is to have a JavaScript array that adds each Task record ID to it on the `onCHange()` event for the task data.

SO when a task is modified, it adds the ID of task to the JS array and then have that array be posted to the server with the AJAX POST.

ON the PHP side, it will take the ID's in this list of id's and select the new datetime values from the DB for each ID in the list and have it generate a JSON response with the task ID and dateTime values for eacfh record that needs to be updated in the DOM.

The AJAX would return this as a JSON response and then update the DOM for each record that needs updating!

After the correct DOM hidden fields are updated, it will clear the JavaScript array and be ready for the next batch of edits.

If a task is deleted before this update then the task ID will be removed from the array of ID's that get posted to the server.

Comment: As far as the original problem, however, I don't think mysql sports OUTPUT. It may be sufficient to consider all results updated, with a following select in the same transaction.

Comment: @user2864740 the issue is that I dont want the dateTIme fields updated for a task `start date` and `completed date` if the task hasn't even been worked on yet!  Also this would break my Gantt charts which use the same data.  So I have to come up with some other clever trick

Comment: How do you track changes client side in event of a rollback? Only in the DOM or do you keep a history array? Also can't you just pull all the times for the array of items sent after the insert/update and return them to client for comparison/update there. Seems like a disconnect already in being able to compare DOM state to db state without doing something like that

Comment: Also, another option you didn't mention is event based updates as opposed to interval based. Basically CRUD request for each client side event. Is easier way to manage concurrency and rollbacks

Comment: @charlietfl As of right now I dont do any kind of rollbak.  I stored ids into in array of records that should be deleted on next save.  MY current issue with setting the DateTIme value before a return from eh DB is that I don't want a user to edit records for 20 minutes and then save and have some dates be 20 minutes different than the real date the DB will create when the real save happens. And yes a more crud event save would be a good option

Comment: I understand that part, the db date needs to prevail. All the more reason to consider event based updates. On each CRUD request return full record or whatever meta data is needed to update client side and keep both in synch

Comment: Added benefit also is no loss of work in situation like power outage, internet connection, browser crash etc

Comment: @charlietfl If you would like to post an answer I can close this out.  Instead of mass-saving with AJAX the better solution to resolve my other issues is to auto-save each record 1 by 1 as the events happen